# Incomplete content (buffer) of webpage

Tags: java, android, web, html, http-get

I want to read the content of a webpage with the following methods, but I only get 60-70 percent of it.

I've tried 2 different methods to read the webpage, both with the same result. I also tried different Urls. I get no errors or timeouts.

What I am doing wrong ?

```
        URL url = new URL(uri.toString());
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    try
    {
        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) 
        {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        br.close();

        this.content = sb.toString();
    }      
    finally
    {
        urlConnection.disconnect();
    }
```

AND

```
    HttpGet get = new HttpGet(uri);
    HttpClient defaultHttp = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
    HttpResponse response = defaultHttp.execute(get);

    StatusLine status = response.getStatusLine();
    if(status.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK)
    {
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        InputStream stream = entity.getContent();
            String encoding = "utf-8";      

        //long length = entity.getContentLength();
        //if(entity.getContentEncoding() != null)
        //{
        //  encoding = entity.getContentEncoding().getValue();
        //}
        //if(length > 0)
        //{
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            long read = 0;
            do
            {
                read = stream.read(buffer);
                if(read > 0)
                {
                    this.content += new String(buffer, encoding);
                }
            }while(read > 0);

        //}
    }
```

@edit

I've tried it with C# and WinForms. I read the complete html source of that webpage.
With java-android it doesn't work.

```
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://www.kicker.de");
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
        string content = reader.ReadToEnd();


        reader.Close();
        response.Close();
```

Comment: Nothing looks wrong at first sight. Can you post the URL?

Comment: I've tried many Urls, but everytime with the same result. If the source of a webseite isn't very small, i don't get the complete source.

Comment: OK, so could you post a URL that did not work for you?

Comment: Ok, f.e. http://www.kicker.de/ (big source) or the feed, that have a smaller source: http://rss.kicker.de/news/aktuell

Comment: Just tested your first code against kicker.de and I received the full content. Have you tried your code outside the Android platform?

Comment: No, only with my Smartphone und virtual Machine. Not yet with a "single" Java-Project but i would try it.

Answer (score 0):

the httpurlconnection in apache's util jar has limited the biggest bytes in a response, i couldn't remember the number of it.

But in most of time ,may you use the http conncetion in UI thread , so sometimes it's not safe,and maybe will be killed, you can choose to deal with the http request in a thread but not the UI thread. So I want to know if you do it in the UT thread

Comment: I've tried in the UI thread and in an other "new" thread. Every time I earned the same result. I didn't get the complete source...

Comment: so you may think if you use the wrong way to read the bytes, there is not only one way to read bytes, you may try some other way to read , hope you will success

Answer (score 0):

I have currently the same Problem. I tried my Code in a simple Java Application and I receive the whole content. But on Android, the Content is incomplete. This Question is now a year old. I guess you have solved it in the meantime. Can you please add your Solution?

**Edit**:
I wrote the content into a File on my Android Device. The Content was complete!
It seems logcat doesn´t show the complete Output you receive from the Devie.